# Junit giving error related to private access in a class FilesMgr and as well as thenReturn(FileStatus)

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, powermockito

Junit giving error related to private access in a class FilesMgr and as well as thenReturn(FileStatus)

Hello All,

Here is the below original class, I've written Junit for `getFilesWithSizes()` method.

```
package com.ms.ets.hive;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;


public class FilesMgr 
        extends HdfsManager {

    private FileSystem fs;

    private final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);

    public FilesMgr (
        String hadoopConfigurationPath)
        throws IOException {

        super(hadoopConfigurationPath);
        this.fs = getFileSystem();
    }


    public Map<String, List<String>> getFilesWithSizes(
        String hdfsPath,
        String pattern)
        throws IOException {

        Map<String, List<String>> files = new HashMap<>();
        List<String> fileInfo = null;
        Path dirPath = new Path(hdfsPath);
        if (fs.isDirectory(dirPath)) {
            Path filter = new Path(String.format("%s/*%s", hdfsPath, pattern));
            FileStatus[] matches = fs.globStatus(filter);
            if (matches != null) {
                for (FileStatus match : matches) {
                    fileInfo = new ArrayList<>();
                    String fileName = match.getPath().getName();
                    fileInfo.add(String.format("%d", match.getLen()));
                    fileInfo.add(getLastModificationTime(match));
                    files.put(fileName, fileInfo);
                }
            }
        }
        return files;
    }


    private String getLastModificationTime(
        FileStatus status) {

        long modificationTime = status.getModificationTime();
        Date modificationTimestamp = new Date(modificationTime);
        return sdf.format(modificationTimestamp);
    }
}
```

Below is my Junit for this:

```
package com.ms.ets.hive;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;  
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Spy;

import com.ms.ets.BacklogManager;
import com.ms.ets.FilesMgr;
import com.ms.ets.HdfsManager;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(value = { FilesMgr.class, UserGroupInformation.class,
        FileSystem.class, HdfsManager.class })
public class HdfsFilesManagerTest {

    private FilesMgr hdfsmgr;
    
    private final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);

    String mockHadoopConfigurationPath;

    Map<String, String> filesWithModTime;
    
    List<Map<String, String>> files;

    @Mock
    private FileSystem mockFileSystem;

    @Mock
    private Configuration mockConfiguration;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mockHadoopConfigurationPath = "mockPath";
        PowerMockito.whenNew(Configuration.class).withNoArguments()
                .thenReturn(mockConfiguration);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(UserGroupInformation.class);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(FileSystem.class);
        PowerMockito.when(FileSystem.get(mockConfiguration))
                .thenReturn(mockFileSystem);
        hdfsmgr = new HdfsFilesManager(mockHadoopConfigurationPath);
    }


    @Test
    public void testGetFilesWithSizes() throws IOException {
        
        String hdfsPath = "/path/to/files";
        String pattern = ".dat";
        Map<String, List<String>> expectedFiles = new HashMap<>();
        List<String> fileInfo = new ArrayList<>();
        fileInfo.add("100");
        fileInfo.add("2023-05-01 12:00:00");
        expectedFiles.put("file1.dat", fileInfo);

        PowerMockito.when(mockFileSystem.isDirectory(new Path(hdfsPath))).thenReturn(true);
        FileStatus mockFileStatus = mock(FileStatus.class);
        PowerMockito.when(mockFileStatus.getPath()).thenReturn(new Path(hdfsPath + "/file1.dat"));
        PowerMockito.when(mockFileStatus.getLen()).thenReturn(100L);
        PowerMockito.when(mockFileSystem.globStatus(new Path(hdfsPath + "/*" + pattern))).thenReturn(new FileStatus(100, true, 1, 100, 1355252400000L, new Path("file1.dat") ));
        PowerMockito.when(hdfsmgr.getLastModificationTime(mockFileStatus)).thenReturn("2023-05-01 12:00:00");

        Map<String, List<String>> result = hdfsmgr.getFilesWithSizes(hdfsPath, pattern);

        assertEquals(expectedFiles, result);        
        
    }
}
```

This Junit fails with below 2 errors:

1. No suitable method found for thenReturn(FileStatus)
2. getLastModificationTime(FileStatus) has private access in FilesMgr

can you please help me out what is wrong in my Junit and give the corrected code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to this example [working with private methods](https://www.baeldung.com/powermock-private-method). You
used the method  when() incorrectly in PowerMockito. And globstatus returns FileStatus[]. so the test should look like this.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(value = { FilesMgr.class, FileSystem.class })
public class HdfsFilesManagerTest {

    @Mock
    private FileSystem mockFileSystem;

    @InjectMocks
    private FilesMgr hdfsmgr;

    private final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(FileSystem.class);
        PowerMockito.when(FileSystem.get(PowerMockito.any())).thenReturn(mockFileSystem);
        hdfsmgr = new FilesMgr("mockPath");
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetFilesWithSizes() throws IOException {
        String hdfsPath = "/path/to/files";
        String pattern = ".dat";
        Map<String, List<String>> expectedFiles = new HashMap<>();
        List<String> fileInfo = new ArrayList<>();
        fileInfo.add("100");
        fileInfo.add("2023-05-01 12:00:00");
        expectedFiles.put("file1.dat", fileInfo);

        PowerMockito.when(mockFileSystem.isDirectory(new Path(hdfsPath))).thenReturn(true);
        FileStatus mockFileStatus = mock(FileStatus.class);
        PowerMockito.when(mockFileStatus.getPath()).thenReturn(new Path(hdfsPath + "/file1.dat"));
        PowerMockito.when(mockFileStatus.getLen()).thenReturn(100L);
        PowerMockito.when(mockFileSystem.globStatus(new Path(hdfsPath + "/*" + pattern)))
                .thenReturn(new FileStatus[] { mockFileStatus });
        PowerMockito.when(hdfsmgr, "getLastModificationTime", mockFileStatus).thenReturn("2023-05-01 12:00:00");

        Map<String, List<String>> result = hdfsmgr.getFilesWithSizes(hdfsPath, pattern);

        assertEquals(expectedFiles, result);
    }
}
```

ACcording to comment. We can create a new FIlestatus like mockFileStatus and then use it in assertion

```
@Test
public void testGetFilesWithSizes() throws IOException {
    String hdfsPath = "/path/to/files";
    String pattern = ".dat";
    Map<String, List<String>> expectedFiles = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> fileInfo = new ArrayList<>();
    fileInfo.add("100");
    fileInfo.add("2023-05-01 12:00:00");
    expectedFiles.put("file1.dat", fileInfo);

    PowerMockito.when(mockFileSystem.isDirectory(new Path(hdfsPath))).thenReturn(true);
    FileStatus mockFileStatus = mock(FileStatus.class);
    Path mockFilePath = new Path(hdfsPath + "/file1.dat");
    PowerMockito.when(mockFileStatus.getPath()).thenReturn(mockFilePath);
    PowerMockito.when(mockFileStatus.getLen()).thenReturn(100L);
    PowerMockito.when(mockFileSystem.globStatus(new Path(hdfsPath + "/*" + pattern)))
            .thenReturn(new FileStatus[] { mockFileStatus });
    PowerMockito.when(hdfsmgr, "getLastModificationTime", mockFileStatus).thenReturn("2023-05-01 12:00:00");

    Map<String, List<String>> result = hdfsmgr.getFilesWithSizes(hdfsPath, pattern);

    assertEquals(expectedFiles.size(), result.size());
    assertTrue(result.containsKey("file1.dat"));

    List<String> actualFileInfo = result.get("file1.dat");
    assertEquals(fileInfo.get(0), actualFileInfo.get(0));
    assertEquals(fileInfo.get(1), actualFileInfo.get(1));
}
```

Comment: Okay, But if we have mockFileStatus object returned in globStatus, then how can we assert with expectedFiles, I think it will fail, can you please advise?

Comment: In the revised code, we build a Path object called mockFilePath that contains the mock file's path, which is equal to hdfsPath + "/file1.dat". For the assertion to be true, we set the same mockFilePath for both mockFileStatus.getPath() and new Path(hdfsPath + "/*" + pattern). Then, we guarantee that the produced map's size and content match those of the expectedFiles.

Comment: okay, but when I ran I got below error:

testGetFilesWithSizes(com.ms.ets.hive.FileMgrTest)  Time elapsed: 1.834 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
String cannot be returned by getModificationTime()
getModificationTime() should return long
*

Comment: Here, we are mocking getLastModificationTime, but how control is going inside getModificationTime and expecting a return from it, even this I couldn't understand

Comment: It is failing with below error:

-org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
String cannot be returned by getModificationTime()
getModificationTime() should return long